# Left joining between a Temp table and History table is giving multiplied result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which retrieves the roles for all employees called `GetAllRoles`.
I inserted the data generating from this stored procedure in a temporary table like below :

Creation of the temp table #RoleTemp :

```
 CREATE TABLE #RoleTemp (

              EmployeeId INT ,
              EmployeeRoleId  int,
              EntityRoleId int, 
              ValueId int , 
              [RoleLabel] VARCHAR(255), 
              SecurityIdentifier VARCHAR(250) , 
              [Role] NVARCHAR(MAX), 
              RoleAccess  VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Population the #RoleTemp table :

```
INSERT INTO #RoleTemp 
EXEC GetAllEmployeeRoles
```

I want to join the #RoleTemp and the Employee_RoleHistory table like below :

```
SELECT rt.EmployeeId,erh.RoleId,erh.CreatedDate AS StartDate,erh.RemovedDate AS EndDate FROM #RoleTemp rt
LEFT JOIN Employee_RoleHistory erh ON rt.EntityRoleId=erh.RoleId
WHERE rt.EmployeeId=5625
```

Instead of getting for each role the StartDate and the EndDate :

```
EmployeeId  RoleId  StartDate                           EndDate 
5625        23      2016-07-12 11:12:33.4900000 6973    2019-01-07 10:29:25.3900000     
5625        25      2019-07-12 11:12:33.4900000 6973    NULL    
5625        233     2018-09-23 11:12:33.4900000 6973    NULL    
...         ...     ...                                 ...
```

I get the result as for each role duplicated many times like below :

```
EmployeeId  RoleId  StartDate                           EndDate 
5625        23      2016-07-12 11:12:33.4900000 6973    NULL        
5625        23      2016-07-12 11:12:33.4900000 6973    NULL    
5625        23      2016-07-12 11:12:33.4900000 6973    NULL    
...         ...     ...                                 ...
```

Comment: Understand your data and check your join condition. all it means is that many records satisfy the results of the join condition. I would recommend to not glass over this with a DISTINCT until you understand what is causing the duplication in the first place.

Comment: Most likely you have the same situation as you had in your previous question - use a windowing function like row_number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand the table relationships to real cause for duplicates and recitfy it by adding proper `ON` condition.

If nothing worked go for `DISTINCT`

Use [**`DISTINCT`**](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php) Clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT rt.EmployeeId, erh.RoleId, erh.CreatedDate AS StartDate,erh.RemovedDate AS EndDate 
FROM #RoleTemp rt LEFT JOIN Employee_RoleHistory erh ON rt.EntityRoleId=erh.RoleId
WHERE rt.EmployeeId = 5625
```